# extending PHP ArrayObject results in wrong subscripted value

Tags: php, arrayobject

The following code prints `1` instead of `4`. Why is that? I am using PHP 7.2.9.

```
<?php
class MyArray extends ArrayObject {
    public function offsetGet($i) {
        if ($i == 'length') {
            return $this->count();
        } else {
            return parent::offsetGet($i);
        }
    }
}
$a = new MyArray;
$a->append(4);
echo $a[0];
```

Comment: I would recommend not using the `offsetGet` method to return the length of the array, rather use the `countable` and implement a `count` method (or use the magic __get method) for that. The `offsetGet` method is basically intended to be used to fetch a value from the array (`[$index]`).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm doing this for a special purpose. Can you explain why this happens?

Comment: When debugging it, it seems like it enters the `if...`, which is quite odd, but if you change the equality operator to a strict one,  it will do as you wish (`===` instead of `==`).

Comment: It's likely due to `'length'` resolves to 0 when converted to integer (can test with: `echo (int)'length';`, it does resolve to 0.

Comment: Further on, I'd say that the strict equal operator is best to use pretty much always. Cases like this could resolve in behavior that you don't notice until further on and could in that case be quite hard to debug! :)

Comment: thanks you all very much!